Is there any way to select the Simple Markup option by default using OfficeJS?
I am trying to set my default on load view of the word document to simple markup but there seems to be no direct function for it in OfficeJS. Does anyone have any idea how to achieve it or any workaround for it?
I have already tried looking into the documentation but didn't find anything there. Preview API will also work. Thanks.

I'm afraid that there is no API in the Office JavaScript Library (Office.js) to do this. But it's a great idea! Please suggest it at Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas.
